# Are sines of primes dense in $[-1,1]?$

Tags: real-analysis, prime-numbers

Let $P$ be the set of all prime numbers. Is $\sin(P)$ dense is $[-1,1]?$ How could we approach such a problem?

Comment: +1 Cool question. What have you tried?

Comment: On distributional principles it sure seems true. Very cool question.

Comment: @draks Well, I know the proof that $\sin(\mathbb N)$ is dense. Actually, I just remembered it from my first course in analysis and thought about this problem. The proof of the case with $\mathbb N$ doesn't seem to generalize, and it would be strange if it did I think. But I have simply no idea how to find another approach.

Comment: I don't know the $\sin(\mathbb{N})$ proof (can you provide a link?), but would it help to think of $\mathbb{N}$ as sum of all primes, semi-primes, k-almost primes?

Comment: @draks There's a [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/sine-function-dense-in-1-1) about it on this site. There's a link to a paper with a proof there but I can't access it from my house so I'm not sure what's in it.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/29338/19341) could help... there it is proven, that $\sum \cos p_n$ does oscillate/diverge. What would happen if $\sin(P)$ is not dense? I think it would clearly diverge. What do you think?

Comment: @draks I only see a proof (a nice one!) that it would follow from the TPC there. Am I missing something?

Comment: The Green-Tao theorem guarantees infinitely long arithmetic progressions within the set $P$ of primes.  However, this fact is not enough yet to conclude that the set $sin(P)$ is dense in $[-1,1]$; and I don't see any extra argument to establish density from the Green-Tao theorem.

Comment: @Jonas, *arbitrarily* long arithmetic progressions. It's not hard to show that *infinitely* long arithmetic progressions are impossible.

Comment: @Gerry: Thanks for correcting that.  I can't believe I wrote that and reread it without noticing.  Of course, the image under sine of any infinitely long arithmetic progression of integers is dense in [-1,1] by the same arguments that work for $\sin(\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article about the discrepancy of a sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrepancy_of_a_sequence#Examples):

> The sequence of all multiples of an irrational $\alpha$ by successive prime
>   numbers, $2 \alpha$, $3 \alpha$, $5 \alpha$, $7 \alpha$, $11 \alpha$, ... is
>   equidistributed modulo 1. This is a famous theorem of analytic number
>   theory, proved by I. M. Vinogradov in 1935.

With $\alpha = \frac{1}{2 \pi}$, this implies that $P$ is equidistributed modulo $2 \pi$.   Using this, and the continuity of the sine function, I think it is straightforward to show that $\sin(P)$ is dense in $[-1,1]$ (although not equidistributed).

Comment: Also, the distribution of $sin(P)$ can be derived from the fact of the equidistribution of $P$ modulo $2\pi$.

Comment: Dan, could you post a link or a reference to Vinogradov's proof?

Comment: @ymar, I couldn't find one with a search, but [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) it is claimed to be "a byproduct of [Vinogradov's work on] the [odd Goldbach conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd_Goldbach_conjecture)".  It is said to have been proven in 1935 so probably the document can be narrowed down on that basis.

Comment: How about $P^{it}$? Is this dense over the unit circle?

Comment: @draks The phase of $P^{it}$ varies extremely slowly for any fixed $t$, so there's no question that it is dense on the unit circle.  One only needs $\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n} \to 1$, which is slightly stronger than Bertrand's postulate and weaker than the Prime Number Theorem.